# javascript not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using this javascript that resizes my the pictures on my site. But it doesn't seem to load the javascript when I am loading the page.
This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("img.picture").each(function () {
    var maxWidth = 100; // Max width for the image
    var maxHeight = 100;    // Max height for the image
    var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
    var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
    var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

    // Check if the current width is larger than the max
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
        $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
        height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }

    // Check if current height is larger than max
    if (height > maxHeight) {
        ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
        $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }
    $(this).show();
  });
 });
```

And this is my header:

```
<link href="Styles/home/photo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ResizePicture.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ChangePicture.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's called ResizePicture.js
Anyone out there got an idea why it doesn't load from the start??

Comment: are you using master pages? if so are you placing it in master page or individual page?

Comment: have you specified the correct path may be its like `src="Scripts/ResizePicture.js"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some browsers image width and height can be fetched after it's been loaded. There are two ways to fix this issue:-

```
define image width and height attrs in html
```

or

change your code to:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("img.picture").each(function () {
    $(this)
     .show()
     .css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $(this).load(function(){
    var maxWidth = 100; // Max width for the image
    var maxHeight = 100;    // Max height for the image
    var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
    var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
    var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

    // Check if the current width is larger than the max
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
        $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
        height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }

    // Check if current height is larger than max
    if (height > maxHeight) {
        ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
        $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }
    $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    })
  });
 });
```

I would rather do resizing in SERVER SIDE script not with js.

Comment: I don't know how you did it... but you solved one of my other problems... If I ever meet you I owe you a large box of beer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a CSS rule be more elegant?

```
img.picture {
 max-height: 100px;
 max-width: 100px;
}
```