# Vertical and horizontal alignment (chrome and safari) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, safari

I use CSS updated by jQuery to center text in a `div`. The `div` height depends on the size of an image. It works well in IE and Firefox but not in Chrome and Safari.

I have tried the following:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var hli = $('#article li').height();

});
```

Instead `$(document).ready()` to catch the height and use it to update the CSS but it always return `0`. You can see an example at this url: http://www.racinedecha.com/test/test.html

The text should appear when the user hovers over the picture.

Comment: Something is missing.  Please post the rest of the relevant code so we can help you.  Or better yet, create a test case in jsFiddle we can play with.

Comment: You have a few problems.  You have a character encoding meta tag between `<html>` and `<head>`; nothing should be there.  Your UTF-8 page is then falling back to `windows-1252` encoding.  You are also  missing a valid `doctype` declaration.  The [HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.racinedecha.com%2Ftest%2Ftest.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) will not work until these issues are fixed.

Comment: I see your JS is between plain `<script>` tags.  Try `<script type="text/javascript">` instead.  You also have commented out content outside the `</html>` tag... you should not have anything after the `</html>` tag.

Comment: You also have HTML comments **within** your JavaScript.  AFAIK, JavaScript will choke on `<!--` and `-->`.  If you want to comment out  sections of JS, use `//` per line or `/*` & `*/` around the whole section.

Comment: the Doctype is a HTML 5 format. and i will use jsFiddle but is it possible to add images ? i will erase my comments javascript as soon as possible.

Comment: If you want to use the HTML5 Doctype, you should look at the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.racinedecha.com%2Ftest%2Ftest.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=00) which thinks your page is HTML 4.01 Transitional. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.racinedecha.com%2Ftest%2Ftest.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#article li img').load(function(){
      var hli = $('#article li').height();
   })    
});
```

EXPLANATION: In Chrome and Safari if the width or height of an image isn't defined then you can't fetch it through your js until the image has been loaded. Now `$(window).load(` doesn't actually wait for each and every image to be loaded that's why I have attached the `load event` to each image and once it's been loaded then you can fetch it's `properties`.

Hopefully that explains the issue. :)

Comment: It's not the same thing, there's difference between `$(window).load` and `$('#article li img').load`

Comment: Then perhaps you can edit your answer to explain why your version would work when the OP's does not.

Comment: I have explained the issue here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945420/javascript-not-loading/7945637#7945637

it's not the exact answer but explains the logic :/

Comment: it seems to work, i have no access to my online version a this time. but i shoud uptdate it as soon as possible. thanks sally

Comment: i had to use this for each instance of variable hli. and it's work perfectly. you save my hair sally, thanks !!!!

Comment: I would be happy to up-vote (+1) once you copy your explanation to within this answer.  The most excellent answers on SO are self-contained without reliance on following links to other questions.

Answer (score 0):

How about just having the text in the html and adding the image as a background-image in the css?

Comment: This suggestion should be in the comments section above.  It's not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: is it possible to adapt dynamically a background image ?